# Graph for values between numbers with R

Tags: r

New to R and trying to do this exercise:

```
"Assign to x the values of all integers from 0 to 10.
Use plot to draw the graph of the function y=3x+2 for values of x between 0 and 10."
```

I know the assigning part:

```
x<-0:10
```

But I don't understand how to write the plot.
I tried:

```
plot(3* (x>=0 && x<=10) +2)
```

But that gives me a plot with only "5", that can't be right.
What is the right way to do it?

Edit for answer:

```
plot(3*x[x<10&x>0]+2)
```

Comment: Isn't this just `plot(x, 3*x + 2)`?

Comment: That gives me a good plot. I think "between" is 1..9.
How can I do that, based on the x?

Comment: You should perhaps see some introduction tutorials to R. For example http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/basicOps.html explains how to do simple vector operations. There are also plenty of tutorials for plotting.

Comment: Your formula was `x>=0 && x<=10` which included the whole range. You can define your `x` as you want, for example `plot(x <- 1:9, 3*x + 2)`. Or you can use subsetting which looks like an overhead here.